# perl IO::Select processing issue after some time

Tags: perl, sockets

I've perl script for unix socket server.pl

```
use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket;

$lsn = new IO::Socket::INET(Listen => 512, LocalPort => 8888);
my $socket_path = '/tmp/punix.sock';
unlink($socket_path);

$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';
$|++;
$lsn = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
Type   => SOCK_STREAM,
Local  => $socket_path,
Listen => 512,
) or die("Can't create server socket: $!\n");

$sel = new IO::Select( $lsn );

while(@ready = $sel->can_read) {
 foreach $fh (@ready) {
    if($fh == $lsn) {
        # Create a new socket
        $new = $lsn->accept;
        $sel->add($new);
    }
    else {
        # Process socket
        my $input = <$fh>;
        #........ do some work
        # 
        # Maybe we have finished with the socket
        $sel->remove($fh);
        $fh->close;
    }
}
}
```

and clients are connecting parallel to socket and getting results.
this is working fine and fastly for first few connections say 60 connections out of 100 connections, after that rest 40 connections are processed slowly like 1 per second.
server.pl seems doesn't have any leaks/issues.
what could be the reason. I've tried with Event::Lib also same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Might relate to `my $input = <$fh>;`. That's wrong. It blocks until a newline is received. You can only safely use `sysread`.

```
our $buf; local *buf = \$bufs{$fh};   # Creates alias $buf for $bufs{$fh}

my $rv = sysread($fh, $buf, length($buf), 64*1024);
if (!defined($rv)) {
   ... handle error ...
   next;
}

if (!$rv) {
   ... handle eof ...
   next;
}

while ($buf =~ s/^(.*)\n//) {
   my $line = $1;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, again it works for some time after that takes more time, if i do strace it's waiting for read in